# How to see static or global variables in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, static, global, eclipse-cdt

I have been trying to figure out how to display static variables in the eclipse variable window for the CDT and can't figure out how. The menu button for the CDT doesn't seem to have the java->globals menu. How do I display static/global variables in eclipse CDT debugger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Window -> Show View -> Expressions`

You can add any expression there, so also global variables.

Comment: is there a way to automatically list all global/static variables?

Answer (score -1):

Arrow down button > Java > Show Constants / Show Static Variables

[image]

Comment: The question is specifically about the CDT, not Java.