# view global/static/inherrited variables in eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

This is a minor annoyance for me that keeps coming up.  When I'm debugging a program I can see variables in the immediate scope, but I can't see variables which are global, static, or variables inherited by 'this' class.  The only way I know how to get these values for testing is to create a dummy variable to store the variable I want within scope of a given function, which isn't efficient or elegant.

Is there an easier way to see the value of any/all of the three variable types I mentioned while stepping through the debugger?

Thanks

Comment: CDT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434107/see-static-variables-in-eclipse-cdt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Expression View](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/expressions/ref-expressions_view.htm) to watch an arbitrary expression, including static and global variables.

Another handy view is the [Displays View](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm), which allows you to execute arbitrary code.

Answer (score 17):

Expanding the entry for `this` in the `Variables` view in the `Debug Perspective` should let you view all of those (non-static) members already, by default.

To view constants and static members, in the `Variables` view's menu (opened by clicking the little down arrow at the top right of the view), choose `Java > Show Static Variables` or `Show Constants`

[image: Show Static Variables]

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I need.  I feel kind of stupid that I wasn't able to find that on my own

Comment: To tell you the truth I had to Google it also! Now we both know :)

Comment: Long annoyance finally gone, thanks! Don't know why I didn't google for this before..

Answer (score 2):

In the Debug Perspective, open the Variables view, click on the downward pointing arrow at the top right of the pane and select Java / Show Static Variables